# React-native-splash-screen statusbar color (incompatible types)

Tags: android, react-native, android-splashscreen, react-native-splash-screen

I'm trying to implement, react-native-splash-screen on my Android APP.

Splash screen works great, but when I try to customize my status bar color (see [docs](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen#getting-started)), I have this error:

> "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean"

[image]

I follow the instructions step by step ([docs](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen#getting-started)). My code is exacly the same

If I remove `R.style.SplashScreenTheme`, all works fine.

PD: Theme name on styles.xml and `R.style.THEMENAME` is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue a while ago.
the package is not being maintained. So probably can't change the status bar color. maybe try [react-native-bootsplash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash). It's a well maintained package and doesnot have any issues like this.

Comment: Yes, I finally decide to move to react-native-bootsplash, thanks!

Answer (score 37):

add a third parameter to `show` function

```
SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme, true);  // false to disable fullscreen
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just downgrade to ^3.2.0 and it will work fine